# Why was the letter "n" in "nor" written in lowercase?

Tags: writing-style, capitalization

Could anyone tell me why the letter "n" in "nor" is in lowercase?

[image]

> Neither Out Far nor In Deep

The above is a title of a poem by Robert Frost.

Comment: I think this is an exception or an editorial error. See here: http://www.online-literature.com/frost/761/ and here: https://www.shmoop.com/neither-far-out-nor-in-deep/ the conjunction "nor" is written in uppercase (capitalised).

Comment: Most examples of this poem found by Google do capitalize "nor".  To ask about poets and capitalization, see e.e.cummings of course.

Comment: Frost is traditional. e.e. cummings is an outlier with purposeful distruption....Normally, one would not capitalize "in". That said, you would if you were contrasting: Out Far and In Deep.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s Lit Crit (or lit crit). Yes, even the titles of works have to be interpreted.

Comment: I think it should be left up as an example of how some types of titles work. Is not title writing and title styles part of English language and usage?? Surely, it is. Not everything in a language can be "proven" but everything can have a reasoned and reasonable explanation.

Comment: So you’re saying that *Neither Far Out Nor In Deep* does not “work”? Do you mean “work for you” or “work for everybody/anybody”? Do you mean it is somehow **untenenable**? @Lambie

Comment: I explain the most likely idea behind the poet's rationale in my answer. How can you possibly think I think it does not work?? I said: we  should leave this question here as an example of how some titles ***work***.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this was not an error.

The APA explanation of ["title case"](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2012/03/title-case-and-sentence-case-capitalization-in-apa-style.html) is this:

> Here are directions for implementing APA’s title case:
>
> Capitalize the first word of the title/heading and of any subtitle/subheading;
>
> Capitalize all “major” words (nouns, verbs, adjectives, adverbs, and pronouns) in the title/heading, including the second part of hyphenated major words (e.g., Self-Report not Self-report); and
>
> Capitalize all words of four letters or more.

This allows a conjunction of three letters or less to be lower case, except when it is the first word.

Of course automatic capitalization by a computer program often simply capitalizes every word, since (the programmer reasons) who cares?

In the book [The Poetry of Robert Frost](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0805005021)

[image: TC]

we see this.  Short conjunctions, prepositions, and articles are not capitalized in the titles of his poems.  But (being done by hand, and not by computer) it is inconsistent.  We can see in that simple "in" both capitalized and not.  In any case, the title as quoted by the OP is the title used by Frost.

Comment: I'm also in the "not an error" camp. I think the capitalization is a way of highlighting that "Out Far" and "In Deep" represent extremes of some continuum.

Comment: @user888379 Hm, where did I read that here?

Comment: @Lambie The perils of asynchronous communication.

Comment: The original, dated 1935, has all the words capitalized https://www.qbbooks.com/pictures/52595.jpg?v=1389999110

Answer (score 1):

**Neither Out Far nor In Deep**

This is Not An Error (rule-wise) but is probably not how the poet wrote it. The poet is always wise, either way. However, it seems it was not the poet who used this.

- Let's accept that the main words in titles are capitalized; that is often the case. Generally, then words like "to" and "and" etc. are not unless they come at the beginning of a title.
- And here if the  poet wanted to emphasize **two states of mind** using a physical idea about people looking at the sea to do so, he could do so by using lower case for nor:

The people along the sand

All turn and look one way.

They turn their back on the land.

They look at the sea all day.

As long as it takes to pass

A ship keeps raising its hull;

The wetter ground like glass

Reflects a standing gull

The land may vary more;

But wherever the truth may be-

The water comes ashore,

And the people look at the sea.

They cannot look **out far**.

They cannot look **in deep**.

But when was that ever a bar

To any watch they keep?

Robert Frost

My conclusion: In the last verse, the poet says that people cannot look out far and they cannot look  in deep (in life or themselves). In the title, he cleverly uses **nor** to foreshadow those two ideas. **To emphasize his pithy "pronunciamento" on the human condition he capitalizes Far Out and In Deep and the lower case "nor" makes them stand out in the title**. This is no typo. He did this on purpose. T

What a great little poem. People look at the sea, boats move over the sea and its always the same surface ("the land varies more). And the people are mesmerized and quite stupid, really. Because they do not a long view of anything and cannot look into anything deeply. So basically, they keep watch and are dumb as posts. Robert Frost is a curmudgeon's curmudgeon. One has to laugh reading his poem so as not to cry......:)

[Sorry, I do not know how to remove double spacing after the lines.]

Comment: All the words are capitalised: https://www.poemhunter.com/poem/neither-out-far-nor-in-deep/, https://allpoetry.com/Neither-Out-Far-Nor-In-Deep, http://www.english.illinois.edu/maps/poets/a_f/frost/outfar.htm, https://www.scipress.com/ILSHS.58.130

Comment: You are right, the originals show all caps. That said, if the nor were lower case, it would follow the rule for only putting non-essential words in lower case, so, my idea does work.

Comment: You stated *Ach, the poet is always wise* so I'm sorry but the insinuation is that the lowercase was intentional when quite the opposite is true. I mean, I don't have a copy of the original poem at hand, and it's not clear by what you mean by "originals". Did you find a 1936 edition online?

Comment: Actually, the poet is always wise, but in this case, the  poet was not the culprit, I was. So, I should change that, which I now have. So my explanation is only moot in case one wants to follow the "little words lower case" -rule.